# Removing first word in a string in C

Tags: c, char, buffer

Hello I am trying to remove the first word in a string.
For example: `buffer = "Hello my name is Code"`
After implementing `removeToken()`, buffer should now be `"my name is Code"`.

The code I have currently is giving me a segmentation fault.

I have the following:

```
char *buffer = NULL;
char *buffercopy = NULL;

void startBuffer(char *inputLine) {
    int length = strlen(inputLine);
    buffer = (char *)malloc(length);
    buffercopy = (char *)malloc(length);
    strcpy(buffer, inputLine);
    strcpy(buffercopy, inputLine);
}

char *removeToken() {
    /* removes the first token from the buffer, buffer is reduced in size */
    char *token;
    char delimiters[2] = " ,";
    int origLen = strlen(buffer);
    token = strtok(buffer, delimiters);
    printf("%s \n", token);
    int p = strlen(token);
    int i = 0;
    while (buffer[i] != '\0') {
        buffer[i] = buffer[i + p];
        i++;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code yourself with a debugger? Do you know where the segfault is occurring?

Comment: Yes! it is occurring in the while loop starting with  "while(buffer[i] != ...."

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

you do not allocate enough memory to copy the strings, you must allocate one extra byte for the null terminator:

```
void startBuffer(char *inputLine) {
    int length = strlen(inputLine);
    buffer = (char *)malloc(length + 1);
    buffercopy = (char *)malloc(length + 1);
    strcpy(buffer, inputLine);
    strcpy(buffercopy, inputLine);
}
```

Note that the above code can be simplified to this:

```
void startBuffer(const char *inputLine) {
    buffer = strdup(inputline);
    buffercopy = strdup(inputline);
}
```

In `removeToken`, you allocate the separator string with:

```
char delimiters[2] = " ,";
```

This is incorrect as you need a third byte for the `'\0'` null terminator.  You can write this instead:

```
char delimiters[] = " ,";
```

You only count the length of the initial string, not the separators, the first of which has been changed to a `'\0'`.

The copy loop therefore stops immediately.

You also forget to copy the final `'\0'` in the copy loop.

Here is a corrected version:

```
char *removeToken(char *buffer) {
    const char *delimiters = " ,";
    size_t i, skip;

    skip = strcspn(buffer, delimiters); /* skip the word */
    skip += strspn(buffer + skip, delimiters); /* skip the delimiters */

    for (i = 0; buffer[skip + i] != '\0'; i++) {
        buffer[i] = buffer[skip + i];
    }
    buffer[i] = '\0';

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much by the way this has worked for me! On this line : skip += strspn(buffer + skip, delimiters); /* skip the delimiters */ I do not understand why you are adding buffer and skip